# Is Partial Derivatives Continuous?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given the function:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x-y}\:\:(x,y)\ne (1,-1)$$
and $$f(x,y)=0\:\:(x,y)=(1,-1)$$

Now i found $f_x=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ as:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=1, (x,y)\ne (1,-1)$$ and $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0, (x,y)=(1,-1)$$ By Taking Partial Derivative for Each piece.

So $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,-1)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=1\ne f_x(1,-1)=0$$
Hence $f_x$ is Discontinuous at $(0,0)$

But my book given it as Continuous.

Comment: Notice that $f$ is neither continuous nor not continuous at $(0,0)$ since it's not defined at that point.

Answer (score 2):

What happens if x = y?  Is that excluded from the domain?
Why the special fuss about x = 1, y = -1 when f(1,-1) = (1 - 1)/2?

As f(x,y) = x + y even for the fussy x = 1, y = -1
and for f extended to all of the real plain, plainly
without pain, f$_x$(x,y) = 1 = f$_y$(x,y).